# Create child repository server from parent repository server in Linux

Tags: yum, repository

If I have Linux YUM repositories configured at server1. How can I add this server1 as the main repo for other servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty pervasive information on the internet, assuming you know what to search for. You need to setup a local YUM repository using server1. Details are described here:

- [Setup Local Yum Repository on CentOS / RHEL / Scientific Linux 6.4](http://www.unixmen.com/setup-local-yum-repository-on-centos-rhel-scientific-linux-6-4/)

The general approach is that you'll need either an FTP server or HTTP server which can access the directory where your RPMs are avaiable (i.e. the `.rpm` files).

With that in place you'll use the `createrepo` command to add the meta data files to the directory that's accessible via FTP/HTTP.

And lastly you'll need to construct a `.repo` file so that YUM knows how to utilize your repository, for example:

```
[localrepo]
name=Unixmen Repository
baseurl=file:///var/ftp/pub/localrepo
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Comment: SO , i have to install either ftp server or http server for accessing such repositories located at server1 "Main Repo" from other servers !!!

Comment: @Eng..Abdalmonem - yes, that's typically how it's done. I host my own repo and that's exactly what I do. If you look inside the `.repo` files included you'll see either `http://` or `ftp://` as well, so you can see which repos are using which protocol. There is no YUM server, if that's what you're looking for.